# Get the URLs from the text

Tags: regular-expression, text-formatting

I get a text file by `apt-get --print-uris dist-upgrade > /mnt/URIs.txt`, I want to download the all packages with the URLs provided by the text file, only the text between '' is URL, How to remove the rest cause only URLs and return symbols are used to download by internet browser.

Comment: You may get more help if you showed the output of the `apt-get --print-uris dist-upgrade` command.  Not everyone here uses a APT-based Linux distribution, or Linux _at all_.

Answer (score 0):

The output from `apt-get --print-uris dist-upgrade` may looks something like this:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common gir1.2-goa-1.0
  gnome-online-accounts libcamel-1.2-62 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20
  libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26
  libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2
  libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libyelp0 linux-libc-dev
  python-apt-common python3-apt yelp
21 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,358 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt-common_2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5_all.deb' python-apt-common_2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5_all.deb 17052 MD5Sum:a9e11f5f8671c5069f5edaef32e2f620
'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python3-apt_2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5_amd64.deb' python3-apt_2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5_amd64.deb 154164 MD5Sum:8590dd473b444f2756e5c7498e00e7ec
'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-online-accounts/libgoa-1.0-common_3.36.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb' libgoa-1.0-common_3.36.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb 3752 MD5Sum:9252da969452bdf88527829a752ac175
```

(this output is truncated)

Assuming you want to parse out the "clean" URIs from the above, the following `sed` command would delete all lines from the first to the one starting with the string `After` (inclusively).  From the remaining lines, it would delete everything after the space, and then delete the first and last characters from the modified line (this would delete the single quotes surrounding the URIs).

```bsh
sed '1,/^After/d; s/ .*//; s/.//; s/.$//'
```

Using this on my short example output above:

```
$ sed '1,/^After/d; s/ .*//; s/.//; s/.$//' file
http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt-common_2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5_all.deb
http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python3-apt_2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.5_amd64.deb
http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-online-accounts/libgoa-1.0-common_3.36.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Given the same input data, the command

```bsh
sed -n "s,.*\(http://[^']*\).*,\1,p" file
```

would also work.  This tries to match any substring that starts with `http://` and ends before a single quote. It then replaces the whole line with that substring and prints the modified line.  Non-matching lines are discarded.